# Excel Find multiple unique values based on multiple search criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89EyL.png)

On the left you see a table with 3 columns and I want to find the result using a formula. The matching criteria are I want all Products from column A that either match "Yes" or "Maybe" OR match 5 in column C.

Full criteria:

- Match "Yes" or "Maybe" in column A
  **OR**
- Match 5 in column C

Whenever I have already matched a Product from column A, I don't want to have it displayed again. This formula should be in such a way that I can drag it down and it displays all the matches.

I have looked into: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fYlWeMQ6L8
but it's growing over my head.

Could anyone please help out?

Comment: I don't follow your result, you show product F in the result list but it does not have yes or maybe, so how are you thinking this?

Comment: that is part of the "OR match 5 in column C"